# How to make an HTTP request from raw data?

Tags: command-line, http

I have some HTTP requests in raw format such as

```
GET /docs/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.nowhere123.com
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
(blank line)
```

I have to test and debug them for this reason I need an easy way to repeat them on my computer, how can I make an HTTP request from raw data using `curl`, `httpie` or another CLI HTTP client?

Comment: It seems you know of `curl` already. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to `echo` then pipe raw HTTP request to `curl` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest telnet: `telnet www.nowhere123.com 80` and you are talking raw to the server.

Example:

`telnet 127.0.0.1 80`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

`GET /index.htm`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https:///index.htm">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```